# Progress bar inside of each list view item is not displayed well

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, progress-bar

I created a ListView, each list item contains a progress bar. When scrolling this list view all progress bars are displayed and scrolled well, EXCEPT very first item with progress bar, which stays always on top. The visual effect is following here: when scrolling down, all progress bars are scrolled well, but additionally new progress bar is always drawn at the fixed position where the first progress bar has been originally displayed. Does anybody know how to get rid of this?

Layout planner_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <include layout="@layout/planner_row"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <include layout="@layout/parent_view"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/no_entries"
        android:textSize="38sp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout planner_row.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_spent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/category_name"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/category_bar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/category_name"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:max="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_limit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/category_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/category_spent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter's main part:

```
public class PlannerListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final PlannerViewHolder holder;
        // create a new row view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planner_row, parent, false);
            // find children views
            TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            TextView tvLimit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_limit);
            TextView tvSpent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_spent);
            ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_bar);

            holder = new PlannerViewHolder(tvName, tvLimit, tvSpent, bar);

            // tag the row with it's children views
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else { // reuse existing row view
            holder = (PlannerViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (dataCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            holder.tvCategory.setText(dataCursor.getString(1));
            holder.bar.setProgress(50);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    ...

    public static class PlannerViewHolder {

        private ProgressBar bar;
        private TextView tvCategory, tvLimit, tvSpent;

        public PlannerViewHolder(TextView tv1, TextView tv2, TextView tv3, ProgressBar b) {
            tvCategory = tv1;
            tvLimit = tv2;
            tvSpent = tv3;
            bar = b;
        }
    }

}
```

Activity's code which uses adapter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setLayout(R.layout.planner_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Cursor c = db.getCategoriesData();
    adapter = new PlannerListAdapter(context, c, new String[] { Data.Categories.NAME, Data.Categories.LIMIT }, new int[] { R.id.category_name, R.id.category_limit });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I am not sure but every time you are loading a row you are setted to 50, so every progress bar will be fixed in the same position, maybe you want to load the progress from db?

Comment: I load data from db, it works well when list view is just displayed, but when starting scrolling, all progress bars are scrolled well (including first one), but additionally android starts always displaying another progress bar at the place of the first one. Unfortunately I can't attach the screenshot as my score doesn't allow it...

Comment: I didn't understand what was your problem, but in your adapter you are inflating as a row the layout planner.xml that contains also a list view. is that normal ?

Comment: I updated my post with the code where adapter inflates as a row just planner_row.xml, while the list view remains in planner_main.xml. But still the issue exists, I will try to explain it in more details: when opening the activity with the list view, all list view items with progress bars are displayed well. But when start scrolling, the progress bar from the first item remains displayed at the original fixed position. It looks like android drew well all progress bars while scrolling, and drew also the 1st progress bar under all of the list view items.

Comment: And this issue exists only when layout for each row contains progress bar, if it contains e.g. only TextView elements, it works fine.